# Javascript setInterval not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have simple code that checks to see if there is a value in an input field, and if there is it gives a Javascript alert window:

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
    if (!jQuery('#input_74_1').attr('value')) {
        alert('There is no value in the field');
    } else {
        alert('There is a value in the field');
    }
  }, 1000);
```

The input field in question is an auto-complete field, so that when I type a letter, suggestions are displayed below the input field. When I click on one of the suggestions, it fills the input field with that value.

However, when I first go to the page I get an alert box "There is no value in the field", but when I start typing and select a suggestion, the input field is filled with the value I selected, but I don't get an alert box that says "There is a value in the field". If this function is set to run every second, shouldn't it be able to tell that there is now a value in the input field, and then display the "There is a value in the field" alert box?

Comment: `window.setInterval()` isn't from jQuery.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me, is there any place you are cancelling the interval, or changing the input's id.

Comment: Use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`.

Comment: `.attr('value')` returns the initial default value, not the current value entered into the input field. `.val()` returns the current enty.

Comment: @TiiJ7 I can't thank you enough ... I was beating my head into the wall trying to figure this out, and that did it!